# Как проверить является ли String, числом формата Long в js

Tags: javascript

Как проверить, является ли строка числом формата Long, а именно 
`long  64 бит  от -9223372036854775808 до 9223372036854775807`

 Пытался сделать простым сравнением, но при числе большем верхней границы выдаёт true

```js
var str = "9223372036854775808"
var isLong = str <= 9223372036854775807
console.log(isLong);
```

Comment: Здесь вся проблема в представлении чисел с плавающей точкой. При очень больших/маленьких значениях возникают дырки, и число округляется к ближайшей доступной точке. Например, для чисел в вопросе, сравнение будет происходить такое: `9223372036854776000<=9223372036854776000` что действительно вернет true

Comment: @Grundy как мне в таком случае проверить строку? isNan подойдёт?

Comment: Скорее всего нет, так как максимальное число в `1.7976931348623157e+308`, то есть любое число меньше вернет для isNaN - false. Если нужно именно проверить указанный интервал, то скорее всего придется сравнивать строки

Comment: @Grundy тут возникнет проблема что "94" больше чем "900" ("94"<"900" - false), поэтому сравнение в строках тоже не подходит

Comment: А никто не сказал, что будет простое сравнение строк :-) в простейшем случае может хватить, сравнения при учете равенства длин

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь вся проблема в представлении чисел с плавающей точкой. При очень больших/маленьких значениях возникают дырки, и число округляется к ближайшей доступной точке. Например, для чисел в вопросе, сравнение будет происходить такое: `9223372036854776000<=9223372036854776000` что действительно вернет true.

Решением может быть обычное сравнение строк. Единственная проблема, для случая когда вход должен быть **целым** числом в диапазоне Long, которая может при этом появиться - это разная длина строк, которая может быть решена добавлением нужного количества 0.

В итоге проверка может выглядеть следующим образом:

1. Проверка знака числа, чтобы знать с какой из границ сравнивать.
2. отбрасывание знака
3. дополнение меньшей строки 0 до нужной длины
4. простое сравнение строк.